# What is this jump instruction for a syscall?

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, system-calls, memory-segmentation

I wanted to see how a syscall is made under x86 on a x64 Windows system, as I'm already familiar with how it's done on x64.

Anyways, I was going instruction by instruction when I came across this `jmp` instruction that I don't understand. Here's the callstack I observed:

```
ntdll.dll!_Wow64SystemServiceCall@0()
ntdll.dll!_NtReadVirtualMemory@20()
KernelBase.dll!ReadProcessMemory()
```

Then, there's a `jmp dword ptr [_Wow64Transition]`. Here's where I'm confused. Right after the jump, there's an instruction `jmp 0033::77CE7009`. Stepping into this instruction will take be back to the end of `ntdll.dll!_NtReadVirtualMemory@20()` for some reason.

What is this far jump, and what does it do?

Comment: I believe this far jump enters a 64 bit code selector.

Comment: *Stepping into this instruction will take be back to the end of ntdll.dll!_NtReadVirtualMemory@20()* this only say that you use bad debugger. good can continue trace

Comment: @RbMm - _good_ and _bad_ are relative terms.  At least offer your idea of a _good_ debugger.

Comment: @ryyker if use for example windbg. and you view next instructions.. say i view `jmp     qword ptr [r15+0F8h]` and it go to `wow64cpu!CpupReturnFromSimulatedCode`

Comment: https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/07/windows-10-system-call-stub-changes.html

Comment: Wow64 does a far call in user-space to switch to 64-bit mode, instead of just using `sysenter` to efficiently call into the 64-bit kernel like Linux does.

Comment: So from what I'm reading, the `jmp` is to a different segment for Wow64, which does all the thunking and stuff, then calls `syscall`?

Comment: Also @fuz if you could make an answer from that comment that'd be great

Comment: @ArushAgarampur I am not sufficiently familiar with the implementation details of Windows (10?) to give an answer that satisfies my quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

You attempted to debug a seg:off jmp with a 32 bit debugger. The instruction trapped in kernel mode by design and trampolined into 64 bit code. The 32 bit debugger is not able to continue debugging and the debugging APIs actually fail until the program returns to 32 bit code again.

If you had a 64 bit debugger you could debug all the way to the system call.

Comment: *trapped in kernel mode* - wait what?  This is a far jmp to a different code segment using a descriptor set up by the kernel (for a 64-bit code segment), but still user-space (low 2 bits = requested privilege level = 3).  AFAIK this stays in user-space until that 64-bit DLL code uses a `syscall` instruction to actually call into the kernel.  (Unlike GNU/Linux where 32-bit code uses `sysenter` or similar to call directly into the kernel's system-call compat layer, instead of doing the compat purely in user-space at the cost of a far jump as well as a syscall.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's jumping to a userspace address but I thought you had to transition to kernel briefly to change processor bitness.

Comment: No, the current bitness simply *is* determined by the segment descriptor selected by CS, changeable with a far jmp, iret, or whatever.  If the kernel has a GDT entry for a 64-bit code segment already set up (with the appropriate privilege level stuff), user-space can just use it to jump from [32-bit-compat sub-mode of long mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes) to full 64-bit.